# Is there any baked in validation classes in C#?

Tags: c#, validation

I want to do simple things anyone in my web app like Checker.Email(string) which would return true or false after doing some regex or something. But I don't want to make this whole thing myself if one already exists...

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ASP.NET then I'd look at the RegularExpressionValidator that's one of the standard .Net Framework controls. Then grab an email regex from www.regexlib.com.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using webforms, there are several ValidationControls you can place on the from, and a slew of third-party controls that use the same system (Inherit BaseValidator or CustomValidator).

Comment: I am using ASP.NET MVC, and have recently been confused about exactly how to wire up some validation. At the moment I am ready to just hand write a checker into my repositories that returns and error code and then just figure out a way for it to hand it back to the form after submit has happened.

Comment: I haven't looked at MVC much yet, but IIRC MVC 2.0 will have much improved/simplified validation helpers.  Not that this helps you right now ...

Comment: Try looking at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153039/asp-net-mvc-client-side-validation

Answer (score 0):

You can use Data Annotations. There is a little tutorial at [asp.net/mvc](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-39-cs.aspx). There's also a [DataType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679282.aspx) attribute that will validate an email for you. If use this method, there's [xVal](http://xval.codeplex.com/) by Steve Sanderson which really makes client/server side validation pretty simple.